# How to unfreeze layers in Inception v3 for transfer learning?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/image_retraining), I can train on the last layer for my own images. I am wondering if I could train on multiple layers?

The structure of the Inception v3 in that tutorial is as below:

[image]

My idea is to add bottlenecks from `mixed_9` instead of `pool_3`, then re-add the structure of `mixed_10` and `pool_3` in the `add_final_training_ops()` function of [`retrain.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py).

Therefore, I call this function before `add_final_training_ops()`.

```
def repeate_last_two_layers(bottleneck_tensor, bottleneck_tensor_size):
  """Adds the last mixed_10 and pool_3 into training."""
  # Use bottleneck to freeze all layers before this one
  with tf.name_scope('new_input'):
    bottle_in = tf.placeholder_with_default(
        bottleneck_tensor,
        shape=[None, 8, 8, bottleneck_tensor_size],
        name='NewBottleneckInputPlaceholder'
    )

  # Use bottleneck input to re-construct mixed_10
  end_point = 'Mixed_7c'
  with tf.name_scope(end_point):
    with tf.variable_scope('Branch_0'):
      branch_0 = slim.conv2d(bottle_in, 320, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
    with tf.variable_scope('Branch_1'):
      branch_1 = slim.conv2d(bottle_in, 384, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
      branch_1 = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[
        slim.conv2d(branch_1, 384, [1, 3], scope='Conv2d_0b_1x3'),
        slim.conv2d(branch_1, 384, [3, 1], scope='Conv2d_0c_3x1')])
    with tf.variable_scope('Branch_2'):
      branch_2 = slim.conv2d(bottle_in, 448, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0a_1x1')
      branch_2 = slim.conv2d(
              branch_2, 384, [3, 3], scope='Conv2d_0b_3x3')
      branch_2 = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[
        slim.conv2d(branch_2, 384, [1, 3], scope='Conv2d_0c_1x3'),
        slim.conv2d(branch_2, 384, [3, 1], scope='Conv2d_0d_3x1')])
    with tf.variable_scope('Branch_3'):
      branch_3 = slim.avg_pool2d(bottle_in, [3, 3], scope='AvgPool_0a_3x3')
      branch_3 = slim.conv2d(
              branch_3, 192, [1, 1], scope='Conv2d_0b_1x1')
      net = tf.concat(axis=3, values=[branch_0, branch_1, branch_2, branch_3])

  # Global pooling
  with tf.name_scope('NewPool_3'):
    net = tf.reduce_mean(net, [1, 2], keep_dims=True, name='GlobalPool')
    # 1 x 1 x 2048
    net = slim.dropout(net, keep_prob=dropout_keep_prob, scope='Dropout_1b')
    # 2048
    logits = slim.conv2d(net, num_classes, [1, 1], activation_fn=None,
                        normalizer_fn=None, scope='Conv2d_1c_1x1')
    logits = tf.squeeze(logits, [1, 2], name='SpatialSqueeze')

  return logits
```

The structures of `Mixed_10` and `pool_3` are referring to the definition in [`inception_v3.py`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py).

It now gives me error:

> ValueError: Dimension 1 in both shapes must be equal, but are 8 and 2. Shapes are [?,8,8] and [?,2,2]. for 'Mixed_7c/Branch_3/concat' (op: 'ConcatV2') with input shapes: [?,8,8,320], [?,8,8,768], [?,8,8,768], [?,2,2,192], [] and with computed input tensors: input[4](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/slim/nets/inception_v3.py) = <3>.

My questions are: 1. Is this the correct way to re-train more layers than the last one? 2. How to copy the structure of `Mixed_10` and `pool_3` in the end of the graph?

Any suggestions are appreciated!